# Exponentiate very large numbers in R

Tags: r, logarithm, exponential

I have the logarithms of very large values, for example:

```
log_a = 1347 
log_b = 1351
```

And I am trying to solve this expression:

```
exp(log_a) - (0.1 * exp(log_b))
```

Or equivalently this (same expression just in a different form):

```
exp( log_a ) - exp( log(0.1) + log_b )
```

But of course every time I try to compute exp(log_a) or exp(log_b) 
values I get Inf. Are there any tricks I can use to get a real result 
for exp(log_a) - (0.1 * exp(log_b)), either in logarithm or 
exponential form?

Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: exp(1351)=exp(1347)*exp(4). Thus, exp(1347) - (0.1 * exp(1351)) = exp(1347)*(1-0.1*exp(4)). The absolute value of that number is too large to be handled by R. Why do you need this?

Comment: Hi Roland, thank you for this. Would it be possible to get the natural log of the result then?

Comment: The result is negative ...

Comment: indeed.. Aren't there any tricks in R to be able to solve this?

Comment: The result is `-antilog(1347 + log(exp(4)*.1 - 1))` which is a huge number to compute.

Comment: `Brobdignag` package ...

Comment: @user971102 This is not an R problem but a computing problem.

Comment: I assume there is a purpose to this large number after you calculate it, so it's possible to roll in some of your later calculations to bring this one into line.  For instance, if you later divided by some number, you could break this formula into chunks of `exp(700)` and apply the division before combining the whole equation.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments! @Dinre, I do have a division after, but I divide the huge logs with each other, so I don't think I can do much before…@Ben, I'll take a look at this package now!

Comment: Thank you to all, these are very clever solutions. I ended up using the package Brobdingnag since it seemed simple, but the other solutions work well too. ThankS!

Comment: Sorry I misspelled `Brobdingnag` (!) -- hope that wasn't too frustrating.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
library(Brobdingnag)
a <- as.brob(exp(1))^1347
a*(1-0.1*exp(4))
#[1] -exp(1348.5)
```

or calculated manually:

```
-(exp(1347+log(0.1*exp(4)-1))=-exp(1347+1.4951...)=-exp(1348.4951...)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
X = exp(log_a) - (0.1 * exp(log_b))
  = exp(log_a) * (1 - 0.1 * exp(log_b) / exp(log_b))
  = exp(log_a) * (1 - exp(-log(10) + log_b - log_a))
  = -exp(log_a) * expm1(-log(10) + log_b - log_a)
```

`expm1` is a built-in function that accurately computes `exp(x)-1` for `x` close to zero. You can get the logarithm of this only if the argument to `expm1` is negative so that the entire expression is positive. Then you can just take the logarithm of the absolute value.

```
log X = log_a + log(-expm1(-log(10) + log_b - log_a))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the gmp library for R, which supports large numbers (arbitrarily big, as far as I know)

for example

```
> bigz('11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111')
Big Integer ('bigz') :
[1] 11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
```

I presume the exponentiation operator is included somewhere in the package. The manual is here: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gmp/gmp.pdf